# How to cache response in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We have some APIs which return exact same response to all calls based on some data which we change from time to time. We have a memcached layer where we have stored the response and have to do a fetch from memcached whenever the calls are received in API. Since there is high frequency of calls to API we would have ideally liked to keep the response cached for 1 minute at API level only (since we do not need immediate invalidation).

Is there some way to store small response data at api/instance level so that we don't need to call the memcached for every request?

Comment: I've never used it but it seems that Python's built-in functools might help.

Answer (score -1):

For high frequency requests I recommend Caffeine:

https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine

This is an in-memory cache solution that works well on instance-level.